# why Laplacian in Cartesian and cylindrical coordinates produces different results?

Tags: laplacian, cylindrical-coordinates

I tried to calculate Laplacian for function $f = \frac{k}{r}$ in both Cartesian and cylindrical  coordinates, but i got different results. To calculate Laplacian in Cartesian coordinates, first i converted function $f = \frac{k}{r}$ to rectangular form $f = \frac{k}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$, then used $\nabla^2f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial z^2}$ formula and i got zero. To calculate Laplacian in cylindrical coordinates, i used $\nabla^2f = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r})+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi^2}+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}$ formula and i got $\frac{k}{r^3}$. I am sure something in my calculations is not rigth, but i don't know what it is. Why i got two different result?

Comment: The $r$ in cylindrical coordinates is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ not $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown ... or the Laplacian in spherical coordinates in $$\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\right)+\frac1{r^2}L(\theta,\phi)$$

Comment: Thank you @@LordSharktheUnknown. with $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ i got $\frac{k}{r^3}$ in both coordinate systems